# Is there a way to alias the command cd so that it protects the arguments?

Tags: bash, directory, alias

When I run

`cd My folder`

There is an error because I have not protected the string.

`bash: cd: My: No such file or directory`

But this works fine

`cd "My folder"`

Is there a way to redefine `cd` as an alias or a function so that it automatically protects all the following arguments as one single string?

This approach did not work, as I supposed it wouldn't:

`cd () { cd "$*" ; }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it, but only if your directory names don't contain several consecutive spaces, and only if they contain no shell special character other than spaces.

```
cd () { builtin cd "$*"; }
```

In practice, use completion: type `cd My` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Bash will insert backslashes before special characters.